# Separar letras de números de String

Tags: java, string

Preciso separar os caracteres de uma string em números e letras.

Ex.:

Entrada:

> "A1B2C3D2Z9"

Saída:

```
List<Character> numeros = { '1','2', '3' }
List<Character> letras = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }
```

Uso um `for` para percorrer a  `string`, só  que não sei como identificar na condição que verifica se a posição da string é um número ou uma letra.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer esse teste condicional?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Verifique se o carácter é um número, usando [`Character.isDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-).

É bom você notar que outros símbolos podem ser usados. Então seria bom usar também o método [`Character.isLetter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-) pra validar se o carácter é realmente uma letra. (Obrigado ao [@diegofm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183112/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-como-separar-letras-de-n%C3%BAmeros-de-string/183115#comment378991_183115) por notar isso).

Abaixo o código validando, letras, números e outros tipos de carácteres.

```
String input = "A1B2C3D2Z9®*#"; //adicionei uns símbolos pro exemplo fazer sentido

List<Character> letras = new ArrayList<>();
List<Character> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
List<Character> outros = new ArrayList<>();

for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        numeros.add(c);
    } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        letras.add(c);
    } else {
        outros.add(c);
    } 
}
```

<sup>[Coloquei o código no GitHub para referência futura.](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/blob/master/Java/183112/separar.java)</sup>

Comment: Character não armazena simbolos unicode nao? Só letras e numeros mesmo?

Comment: Me refiro ao outros simbolos, tipo ®.

Comment: Boa, @diegofm. Complementei a resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Na biblioteca do `Character` tem um metodo `isDigit` que checa se o caractere é um número de 0-9

```
char c = string.charAt(0);
if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    //É numero
} else {
    //É letra
}
```

Nessa pergunta do SO Gringo tem várias ideias: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223052/how-do-i-find-out-if-first-character-of-a-string-is-a-number

Comment: Questiono o mesmo caso da outra resposta, nem todo caracter é somente letra ou número, a segunda validação pode trazer resultados errados.

Answer (score 4):

Alternativa simples utilizando `replaceAll` e `regex`

```
String input = "A1B2C3D2Z9";
String letters = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
String numbers = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");

//Para transformar em array
letters.toCharArray();
numbers.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

É apenas a solução do mesmo problema com um outro sabor.

```
String chars = "A1B2C3D44F555";
List <Character> letters = chars.chars().
                              boxed().
                              map(ch -> (char) ch.intValue()).
                              filter(Character::isLetter).
                              collect(Collectors.toList());
List <Character> digits = chars.chars().
                             boxed().
                             map(ch -> (char) ch.intValue()).
                             filter(Character::isDigit).
                             collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Essa solução é mais lenta por fazer Autoboxing duas vezes na lista.

Comment: Gostei da solução! **+1** Só tua descrição ficou meio "agressiva" =D

Comment: Desculpa. Quis ser irônico. Comecei a utilizar, e ainda estou me adaptando.